# Python multiprocessing Process PID is different from actual PID

Tags: python, pid, python-multiprocessing

This is my code. I am trying to create n(=10 here) processes and just trying to see their PIDS. When I print them and verify the PID in terminal, they are not the same. EDIT : I am running this on a Mac (Yosemite) if that helps.

```
for proc in xrange(10):
        worker_process = Process (name="worker_process", target=worker_code, args=(proc, tree_space, self.simulator, mgr_nms))
        process_q.append(worker_process)
        worker_process.start()
        print worker_process.pid
```

My Output:

```
60484
60485
60486
60487
60488
60489
60490
60491
60493
60494
```

Terminal Output (top):

(IMAGE) -> http://postimg.org/image/kkiboom6l/

Any pointers regarding why this is ? (sorry if I am missing something so obvious.)

Comment: Try printing multiprocessing.current_process().pid from the worker threads and add them to comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I see two PPID's (parent PID's) in your screenshot: 60480 and 60481 (far right side).

Are you sure you are not running your program twice? The screenshot is cut off, but I'm guessing you would see 20 Python processes there if you are indeed running your code twice.

I am already counting 14 Python processes in total from that screenshot, where there should be at most 11.

**EDIT:**

Actually the PPID of 60481 is 60480. So it looks like you are running this program once, but are spawning processes (using `Process()`) earlier than the code you provided here. That is most likely the source of your problem.

Comment: In fact, since Python is a part of the Mac OS X operating system, some could be system threads, while the others are from execution.

Comment: @Zizouz212 That's not the case here. They all have the same PPID's.

Comment: @Martin I didn't change the code after edits. Could you please elaborate the problem and tell me the exact change that is needed ? Thanks a ton !

Comment: @Aragorn, what I'm saying is that you must be creating processes somewhere before the code that you have provided in your question. Can you confirm if you are using `Process` elsewhere in your code?

Comment: @Martin, I just checked and I am sure that there are no Process creation before that. I created another Python file and spawned 10 processes. It works. But this code isn't working the way it's supposed to be.

Comment: @Martin I have a created a manager() process ! That adds for something ?

Comment: Yes that explains the extra processes we are seeing, but that is not the problem. BTW, updated my answer.

Comment: What happens if you sleep in each of your spawned processes (say sleep for 20 seconds), and then look at your process list in OS X? I suspect your processes are simply exiting before you see them in the process manager. That doesn't explain the extra processes however.

Comment: @Martin - Solved it. I am actually creating a bunch of new Manager().Lock() inside and every time I create it, a new process spawns up. My goal was to  make sure every process exits properly. I just created a list of all the managers and shut them at the end. (previously I thought of getting a list of all PIDs and kill them on my own). Still this doesn't explain why the ID from Process() is different from actual PID on terminal. But my goal is achieved :) Thank you for the help. Would like to know your thoughts about the ID problem though.

Comment: How long do you expect your child process to run? As mentioned, I believe you aren't seeing all of them in your terminal due to them having already been completed.

Comment: Yes they run for a while. I am seeing them in the terminal for a while and they get terminated (after my changes in the code). Previously they all were just staying there and not getting closed.